# how to show removing zero elements from a vector in math?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, notation

Let us think we have a vector with mostly zero elements and few valued elements, such as :

A=[0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0]

What is the mathematical notation for an operation that removes zeros? The remaining vector is :

B=[1,2]

Comment: I doubt there is a common notation for this uncommon (in mathematics) operation

Comment: Not sure if such an operation exists. You may define one (rigorously). Let me know if you need help.

Comment: **projecting** in a k-tuple constructed with the non zero entries of an n-tuple

Comment: I would guess that if this is an operation you need, then possibly vectors aren't the right mathematical object to be using. Maybe a better description of what you are trying to do can help this question lead to better answers.

Comment: You can go on an define your own notation, that's completely legitimate if you make the definition clear enough.

Comment: I think @MorganRodgers is spot on. If something doesn't make sense when one changes the basis then we are probably not discussing a vector-space property. From your description I think you're just operating on finite strings, and you can easily describe this recursively using the usual string operations. And this would avoid, too, the difficulty of what you're to do with the zero "vector" - there is an empty string.

Comment: If the answers so far are not useful to you, I suggest editing the question to explain **why** you would want to do such a thing. Preferably it is a reason that will have people saying, "Aha, that's an interesting problem" and not, "Why would anyone do such a silly thing?"

Answer (score 1):

As is suggested in the comments, vectors are not a correct way to look at this. A very simple, but important reason is that given a vector, you don't know how many zero entries it will have, so codomain, if we want it to be a vector space, would be ill-defined. Another reason is that such a map would clearly not be linear as it would not send zero vector to zero vector, so linear algebra is not how one should approach this.

What you have in mind looks to me to be better approached using [lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)), but we don't need all of the list operations, so I will just talk about necessary stuff. Mathematically, we would consider some set $X$ and [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) $F(X)$ generated by $X$. In your case you can take $X$ to be the field you would consider your vector space to be over. Let us just pick a field $k$ and let $0$ be it's additive identity.

Now, to describe your operation, let us form the free monoid $F(k)$. To describe elements of $F(k)$, I will use your notation, for example, for any $x\in k$, we can write $[x]$ as an element of $F(k)$. Or, we could write $[x,y,x,x,z]$ for some $x,y,z\in k$. This might sound fancy if you are not familiar with it, but you can think of $F(k)$ as the set of all words formed using alphabet $k$. Multiplication is just concatenation, for example, $$[x,y,z]\cdot[z,x] = [x,y,z,z,x].$$ Identity in $F(k)$ is empty word/list/string $[\,]$.

Define function $f\colon k\to F(k)$ by setting
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
[x],& x\neq 0,\\
[\,],& x = 0.
\end{cases}$$

By the universal property of a free monoid, there exists a unique monoid homomorphism $$\mu\colon F(k) \to F(k)$$ such that $\mu([x]) = f(x)$. The important thing is that $\mu$ is multiplicative, so, for example
\begin{align}
\mu([1,0,2,0,0]) &= \mu([1]\cdot[0]\cdot[2]\cdot[0]\cdot[0])\\
&= \mu([1])\cdot \mu([0]) \cdot \mu([2])\cdot \mu([0])\cdot \mu([0]) \\
&= f(1)\cdot f(0)\cdot f(2)\cdot f(0)\cdot f(0) \\
&= [1]\cdot [\,] \cdot [2] \cdot [\,] \cdot [\,] \\
&= [1,2].
\end{align}

The map $\mu\colon F(k)\to F(k)$ is indeed a unary operation that does what you described, but I am not familiar if there is a standard name or notation for it.

Comment: I think your answer perfectly works in the way OP intended, but maybe they were searching for a straight forward notation - of course, one could denote your map via a symbol. Maybe OP finds the procedure cumbersome?

Comment: @Plasma Stark, literal answer to the question as is currently posed is: there is very likely no standard notation. However, if one would want to do it, vectors are not a way to go, hence my answer. The procedure may or may not be cumbersome, but that's how you would do it, anyway. If someone knows how to do it in a more elementary way, I'm looking forward to seeing it. The other thing is that this looks like something one would like to do when writing some code and this is why I brought up lists. This is how you do it mathematically. Not a notation, but at least some context.

Comment: Absolutely correct, and judging by OP's post history they are interested in the code side of this.

Answer (score 0):

I may be totally off, but that should be a projection on a subspace: of course it depends on what you're working on, but I guess you are implicitly considering $\mathbb{R}^8$ with the usual canonical base, so by considering $\pi$ the projection of $\mathbb{R}^8$ to $\mathbb{R}^2_{e_4,e_6}$ - where $\mathbb{R}^2_{e_4,e_6}$ is of course my own weird notation for the two-dimensional subspace generated by those two components - you should get what you are searching for, which is
$$ \pi(A)=\pi([0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0])=[1,2]=B$$
It should be noted though this is no common operation, but with the projection you should be able to make it work mathematically speaking. I am also covering up the use of an isomorphism $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{R}^2_{e_4,e_6}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, and that is what's making components "disappear", so what you should really be using is $\varphi(\pi(A))$ **and not** $\pi(A)$. See [Wikipedia's page on projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)) for more.

---

**Edit & correction:**

As @Ennar correctly pointed out,
the map I defined works fine only if you know where the zeroes are, which I incorrectly assumed you did.

If you want to take a set of given vectors and just crop out the zeroes vectors and projections are not the best structures to use: you would have to redefine the projection for each vector manually.

Comment: The map that you define would send zero vector to zero vector, which is not removing all zeroes. On the other hand, it would remove non-zero entries as well in some cases.

Comment: @Ennar I see, you are absolutely right and made me realise I misinterpreted the question then, OP wants to remove all zeroes every time and not just from already given vectors... I'll edit it, ty!